# How to remove SLPRJ folders?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have multiple Simulink models in different folders and they each have a SLPRJ folder in them. I would like to know what is the MATLAB command that I should use to remove the SLPRJ folder before loading a specific Simulink model?

Comment: Did you try `rmdir` ?

Comment: Indeed, `rmdir` is working, but I was looking for the Simulink command, since it's generated by the compilation of a Simulink model.

Comment: An other possibility would be to store the slprj folder in a Matlab system folder instead of in the same folder as the Simulink model file under consideration.